# Ubuntu server 20.04 no internet connection

Tags: networking, static-ip, ubuntu-20.04

I have a host with Ubuntu server 20.04 installed on it.
The server is connected with ethernet cable to a PowerLine repeater.
After installation, there is no internet connection; so, I searched on google and I found I have to manipulate Netplan.
I did it, configuring the configuration file to set a static IP, but it still does not works.

This is my current Netplan yaml file code:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp4s0:
     dhcp4: no
     addresses: [192.168.1.20/24]
     gateway4: 192.168.1.1
     nameservers:
       addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
```

where, of course, `192.168.1.20` is the static IP form my server and `192.168.1.1` my gateay, which is my home router.

I checked my routes, to find if default duplicated routes are present, but seems not. This the output of `ip route` command:

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp4s0 proto static 
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp4s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.20
```

I checked also the `resolv.conf` file, but it is set with only google DNS entry:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

The IP seems to be well configured after netplan change applied:

```
root@ubuntuserver:~# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e0:3f:49:7c:60:45 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.20/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global enp4s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::e23f:49ff:fe7c:6045/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wg0: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1420 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/none 
    inet 192.168.66.4/32 scope global wg0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

However, I'm still without internet connection.

What further actions should I perform?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.